# Loss of 20+Gb of space and cannot find out why (amazon mysql rds)

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am trying to figure out why one of my MYSQL RDS DB instances lost 20+GB of storage space and I cannot figure out why. I have 2 RDS instances and am using some queries to compare data + free data usages.  (Both have innodb_file_per_table = 0)

Is my analysis correct on how to determine how much free disk space there should be? What else could cause a huge discrepancy between how much amazon rds reports as free space and how much I am calculating (DB 1 is way off and DB 2 is pretty close)

```
DB 1
----------------------------------

PHP POS DB disk size 150 gb
Data usage = 33.2gb
Free space usage = 27.4 gb
Calculated Free Space (150 - 33.2-27.4) = 89.4 gb
Actual Free Space = 57.5 gb


mysql> SELECT sum((data_length+index_length)/1024/1024) AS MB from information_schema.tables;
+----------------+
| MB             |
+----------------+
| 33207.82419395 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (5.40 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(data_free / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'MB') FREE_Space from information_schema.TABLES ORDER BY data_free DESC LIMIT 1;
+------------+
| FREE_Space |
+------------+
| 27430.00MB |
+------------+
1 row in set (5.36 sec)




DB 2
PHP POS DB 2 Disk Size 150 gb
Data usage =  36.7
Free Space Usage= 1.9
Calculated Free Space (150-36.7 - 1.9) = 111.4 
Actual Free Space = 107gb

----------------------------------
mysql> select table_schema, sum((data_length+index_length)/1024/1024) AS MB from information_schema.tables;
+--------------------+----------------+
| table_schema       | MB             |
+--------------------+----------------+
| information_schema | 36717.22916222 |
+--------------------+----------------+
1 row in set (3.26 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(data_free / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'MB') FREE_Space from information_schema.TABLES ORDER BY data_free DESC LIMIT 1;
+------------+
| FREE_Space |
+------------+
| 1885.00MB  |
+------------+
```

UPDATE

DB 1

```
mysql> SELECT  MAX(table_name) AS SampleTable, COUNT(*),
    ->         CONCAT(ROUND(data_free / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'MB') FREE_Space
    ->     from  information_schema.TABLES
    ->     WHERE  engine='InnoDB'
    ->       AND  data_free > 1e6
    ->     GROUP BY 3
    ->     ORDER BY 2 DESC
    ->     LIMIT 22;
+--------------------+----------+------------+
| SampleTable        | COUNT(*) | FREE_Space |
+--------------------+----------+------------+
| subscriptions      |    45028 | 27305.00MB |
| innodb_index_stats |        1 | 32.00MB    |
| innodb_table_stats |        1 | 4.00MB     |
+--------------------+----------+------------+
3 rows in set (11.92 sec)
```

DB2

```
mysql> SELECT  MAX(table_name) AS SampleTable, COUNT(*),         CONCAT(ROUND(data_free / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'MB') FREE_Space     from  information_schema.TABLES     WHERE  engine='InnoDB'       AND  data_free > 1e6     GROUP BY 3     ORDER BY 2 DESC     LIMIT 22;
+--------------------+----------+------------+
| SampleTable        | COUNT(*) | FREE_Space |
+--------------------+----------+------------+
| rds_sysinfo        |    29967 | 1886.00MB  |
| innodb_index_stats |        1 | 73.00MB    |
| innodb_table_stats |        1 | 5.00MB     |
+--------------------+----------+------------+
3 rows in set (8.88 sec)
```

Comment: On the second query in each, change `SELECT` to `SELECT *,`  You may be in for a surprise.

Comment: Are these two separate clusters or are they the same cluster with db2 the read replica?  Also is it MySQL or Aurora MySQL compatible?

Comment: MySQL 5.6 different clusters; not read relicas

Comment: I conclude that `ibdata1` has 27GB free on DB1 and 1.9GB free on DB2.  But I don't know how that helps discover the base issue.

Comment: It does sound like DB2 _may_ have glommed onto a bunch of space recently.

Comment: (45K tables is on the "high side" of things.)

Comment: I just don’t get how 20+gb went away. There has high write iops happening but new relic didn’t report anything in application that would cause this.

Comment: I was thinking that adding the data used a free space used would help find actual free disk space

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT  MAX(table_name) AS SampleTable, COUNT(*),
        CONCAT(ROUND(data_free / ( 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'MB') FREE_Space
    from  information_schema.TABLES
    WHERE  engine='InnoDB'
      AND  data_free > 1e6
    GROUP BY 3
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
    LIMIT 22;
```

What do you conclude from the output about your second query?

Comment: I added the quey results